# Crossport requests Errors.

Tags: node.js, port, vue.js

So what I am trying to do is hosting frontend and backand on the same port. But it is not really working. So I put them on different ports. Now I am getting an error when trying to do crossport requests.

My frontend is made with a webpack vuejs boiler plate. Its ran via `npm run dev`.
My backend is a nodejs express server that acts as an REST API. Both are running on different ports.

So I am trying to make get request with vuejs from my frontend to my backend. But when I make the request I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8000/api/user. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

This is the code that sends the request:

```
register: function(){
      this.$http({url: 'localhost:8000/api/user', method: 'GET'}).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      }, function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
    }
```

The backend parts:

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/user')
  .get(userController.test)
// Register all our routes with /api
app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(8000);
```

And the function:

```
exports.test = function(req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'done'});
};
```

I hope someone will be able to help me :)
Or if someone has a solution for me to put them both on the same port without it prioritizing the node server then that would be amazing too. Because when I load localhost:8080 it goes straight to the backend server instead of the frontend.